# Cyclic permutation of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, permutations

Consider a generic, strictly positive, joint probability distribution $p(x,y,z)$.

Is the following formula:
$$
p(x|y)\,p(y|z)\,p(z|x) = p(y|x)\,p(z|y)\,p(x|z)
$$

always true?

I can prove it in specific simple examples, but not for the general case...so I was wondering.

Thanks!

(Feel free to modify tags appropriately.)

Comment: Using Baye's conditional probability, expand the left hand side and the right hand side. You'll find that they are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's always true. Using Bayes:
\begin{align*}
p(x|y)p(y|z)p(z|x) &= \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}\frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)}\frac{p(z,x)}{p(x)}\\
&= \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}\frac{p(z,y)}{p(y)}\frac{p(z,x)}{p(z)}\\
&=p(y|x)p(z|y)p(x|z)
\end{align*}